# App to locate device within the home (Indoor positioning)

Tags: networking, mobile, geo-location, home-automation

I want to be able to quickly check the location of my dog -- which room of the house or part of the yard that she's in.

I have a GPS collar for her, but I've decided not to use GPS because of

- the expensive of paying for a data plan and
- the significant lack of precision, particularly indoors

On the hardware side I can think of several obvious solutions:

- Bluetooth
- RFID
- WiFi
- Any of the above technologies being used as a dongle for her collar either

  - independently based on proximity from a computer or router
  - or (more likely) in combination with beacons in each room + my router

However I don't know of a software solution to manage the hardware in this way.

Ideally I would like to interface with it through my Echo (Amazon's voice-controlled home automation hub) so that it would be like on Star Trek where I go "Computer, locate Lt. Puppy" and Echo will be like "Lt. Puppy is in the Holodeck".

I believe that I could write the app (the "skill" in Amazon-speak) to integrate the app with Echo though, if such an app exists.

It seems like there are a lot of apps that do this for larger scale -- for instance, I already have [TrackR](https://www.thetrackr.com/bravo/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=Bravo_Search_GeneralKeywords_cpc&utm_campaign=Bravo_Search_GeneralKeywords) but they don't work within the home.

I am open to Windows, Linux, mobile or web-app solutions. Basically anything except MacOS.

**Update:** I found this related Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indoor_positioning_system ... come to think of it, I used to work for an evil location-based advertising company called Jiwire that talked about determining your exact location within a store (e.g. which aisle of a grocery store you're in) based on your mobile data and using that to display related ads on your phone...

Comment: Your dog is called "Lt. Puppy"? Sounds great (until you have to call her in the park ;-)

Comment: @Mawg LOL well she's only called that for the purposes of this question. Her real name is Georgia.

Comment: @Mawg Thanks It looks like it's just not available on the app but it works now that I'm using a web browser

Comment: Its not an answer yet as I am still writing the app.  I have installed beacons above the ceiling in each room.  And have finished a proof of concept app that figures out where the phone is at any given time.  I just need to convert it to a service before starting to use it fully.  I also have a Fibaro (Home automation) system where I have written a Virtual Device to grab this information.

Answer (score 1):

The [TrackR](https://www.thetrackr.com/atlas) can be joined by [TrackR Atlas](https://www.thetrackr.com/atlas) devices to provide indoor location mapping & boasts Alexa integration via the TrackR App for [iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/item-trackr-find-your-wallet/id588363491?mt=8) or [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phonehalo.itemtracker). TrackR Atlas can also *apparently* be used with other bluetooth enabled devices.

You can see more details on the [crowdfunding site](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/trackr-atlas-effortless-organization#/) - it seems it will even work with other Alexa devices than the echo.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't heard of the Atlas flavor of TrackR, so I will check that out. As mentioned in the question, I already have TrackR tho but it doesn't work indoors and actually doesn't really work very well outdoors either as you can go miles before hitting another TrackR user. **Update** Yes, TrackR Atlas sounds like it would be perfect but of course it unfortunately has not been released yet. I will definitely keep an eye on it tho.